# How to run statemine with polkadot-launch?

Tags: statemine, polkadot-launch

I am trying to run `statemine` in `polkadot-launch`. I have get 0.9.18 versions of `polkadot` and `polkadot-collator`. And trying to run like next:

```
{
  "relaychain": {
    "bin": "../../../polkadot/target/release/polkadot",
    "chain": "kusama-local",
    "genesis": {
      "runtime": {
        "runtime_genesis_config": {
          "configuration": {
            "config": {
              "validation_upgrade_frequency": 2,
              "validation_upgrade_delay": 2
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "nodes": [
      {
        "name": "alice",
        "wsPort": 9944,
        "basePath": "/tmp/polkadot-launch/relaychains/alice",
        "port": 30444,
        "flags": ["--rpc-cors=all", "--beefy", "--enable-offchain-indexing=true"]
      },
      {
        "name": "bob",
        "wsPort": 9955,
        "basePath": "/tmp/polkadot-launch/relaychains/bob",
        "port": 30555,
        "flags": ["--beefy"]
      },
      {
        "name": "charlie",
        "wsPort": 9966,
        "basePath": "/tmp/polkadot-launch/relaychains/charlie",
        "port": 30666,
        "flags": ["--beefy"]
      },
      {
        "name": "dave",
        "wsPort": 9977,
        "basePath": "/tmp/polkadot-launch/relaychains/dave",
        "port": 30777,
        "flags": ["--beefy"]
      },
      {
        "name": "ferdie",
        "wsPort": 9978,
        "basePath": "/tmp/polkadot-launch/relaychains/ferdie",
        "port": 30778,
        "flags": ["--beefy"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "parachains": [
    {
      "bin": "../../../cumulus/target/release/polkadot-collator",
      "chain": "statemine-local",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "name": "alice",
          "wsPort": 9988,
          "basePath": "/tmp/polkadot-launch/parachains/alice",
          "port": 31100,
          "flags": ["--", "--execution=wasm"]
        },
        {
          "name": "bob",
          "wsPort": 9997,
          "basePath": "/tmp/polkadot-launch/parachains/bob",
          "port": 31200,
          "flags": ["--", "--execution=wasm"]
        },
        {
          "name": "charlie",
          "wsPort": 9996,
          "basePath": "/tmp/polkadot-launch/parachains/charlie",
          "port": 31300,
          "flags": ["--", "--execution=wasm"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "types": {},
  "finalization": false,
  "simpleParachains": []
}
```

I see relay blocks produced but not statemine.

I able to produce blocks on my parachain network. And also tried rococo for relay and statemine-dev/local in above config, no results.

[image: Statemine several collators]
[image: Statemine no blocks]
[image: Statemine is parachain]

UPDATE:

Logs seems fine

```
2022-05-11 15:55:10 Polkadot collator    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 ✌️  version 5.3.0-b1e91afb7-x86_64-linux-gnu    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2022    
2022-05-11 15:55:10  Chain specification: Statemine Local    
2022-05-11 15:55:10   Node name: Alice    
2022-05-11 15:55:10  Role: AUTHORITY    
2022-05-11 15:55:10  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/substratejHBiJi/chains/statemine_local/db/full    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 ⛓  Native runtime: statemine-800 (statemine-0.tx5.au1)    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 assembling new collators for new session 0 at #0    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 assembling new collators for new session 1 at #0    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 Parachain id: Id(1000)    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 Parachain Account: 5Ec4AhPZk8STuex8Wsi9TwDtJQxKqzPJRCH7348Xtcs9vZLJ    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 Parachain genesis state: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c167e2803b46f80dace0bc13481465390c9011b17b8403845d606361c197495703170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c11131400    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 Is collating: yes    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 [Parachain] assembling new collators for new session 0 at #0    
2022-05-11 15:55:10 [Parachain] assembling new collators for new session 1 at #0    
2022-05-11 15:55:11 [Parachain]  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xc167…4957, header-hash: 0xb8cd…390b)    
2022-05-11 15:55:13 [Relaychain]  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xeb9f…680a, header-hash: 0x69b2…082e)    
2022-05-11 15:55:13 [Relaychain]  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-05-11 15:55:14 [Relaychain]  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-05-11 15:55:14 [Relaychain]   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWHx7EaXTHvQQJ9zqdAwreArUaiCjQEeZxd5VDUqKXo9uE    
2022-05-11 15:55:14 [Relaychain]  Highest known block at #0    
2022-05-11 15:55:14 [Relaychain] 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9616    
2022-05-11 15:55:14 [Relaychain] Listening for new connections on 127.0.0.1:9945.    
2022-05-11 15:55:14 [Parachain] Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs    
2022-05-11 15:55:14 [Parachain]   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWLPW6TyqXc8mGJTuARXCbMR3WLvPkDjPcvPyTFZpn5s76    
2022-05-11 15:55:14 [Relaychain]  New epoch 0 launching at block 0x1da5…73bc (block slot 275380152 >= start slot 275380152).    
2022-05-11 15:55:14 [Relaychain]  Next epoch starts at slot 275380752    
2022-05-11 15:55:14 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #1 (0x1da5…73bc)    
2022-05-11 15:55:15 Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:39826.    
2022-05-11 15:55:15 [Parachain]  Highest known block at #0    
2022-05-11 15:55:15 [Parachain] Unable to bind RPC server to 127.0.0.1:9933. Trying random port.    
2022-05-11 15:55:15 [Parachain] Listening for new connections on 127.0.0.1:9988.    
2022-05-11 15:55:17 Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:39852.    
2022-05-11 15:55:18 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #2 (0x2cd9…2123)    
2022-05-11 15:55:18 Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:50682.    
2022-05-11 15:55:19 [Relaychain]  Idle (5 peers), best: #2 (0x2cd9…2123), finalized #0 (0x69b2…082e), ⬇ 9.3kiB/s ⬆ 6.1kiB/s    
2022-05-11 15:55:20 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xb8cd…390b), finalized #0 (0xb8cd…390b), ⬇ 4.0kiB/s ⬆ 3.2kiB/s    
2022-05-11 15:55:24 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #3 (0x0ed5…a7c0)    
2022-05-11 15:55:24 [Relaychain]  Idle (6 peers), best: #3 (0x0ed5…a7c0), finalized #0 (0x69b2…082e), ⬇ 5.2kiB/s ⬆ 5.0kiB/s    
2022-05-11 15:55:25 [Parachain]  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0xb8cd…390b), finalized #0 (0xb8cd…390b), ⬇ 1.3kiB/s ⬆ 1.3kiB/s    
2022-05-11 15:55:29 [Relaychain]  Idle (7 peers), best: #3 (0x0ed5…a7c0), finalized #1 (0x1da5…73bc), ⬇ 2.8kiB/s ⬆ 2.9kiB/s    
2022-05-11 15:55:30 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #4 (0x6ace…4244)    
2022-05-11 15:55:30 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #4 (0xb656…7bcc)    
2022-05-11 15:55:30 [Parachain]  Idle (2 peers), best: #0 (0xb8cd…390b), finalized #0 (0xb8cd…390b), ⬇ 1.1kiB/s ⬆ 1.0kiB/s    
2022-05-11 15:55:34 [Relaychain]  Idle (7 peers), best: #4 (0x6ace…4244), finalized #1 (0x1da5…73bc), ⬇ 3.5kiB/s ⬆ 2.3kiB/s    
2022-05-11 15:55:35 [Parachain]  Idle (2 peers), best: #0 (0xb8cd…390b), finalized #0 (0xb8cd…390b), ⬇ 0.5kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-05-11 15:55:36 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #5 (0x483e…686f)    
2022-05-11 15:55:36 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #5 (0x3375…4531)
```

and

```
2022-05-11 16:05:52 [Relaychain]  Idle (6 peers), best: #21 (0x7c26…8c8f), finalized #19 (0xf4da…23f4), ⬇ 2.2kiB/s ⬆ 2.0kiB/s    
2022-05-11 16:05:53 [Parachain]  Idle (2 peers), best: #0 (0xb8cd…390b), finalized #0 (0xb8cd…390b), ⬇ 74 B/s ⬆ 74 B/s
```

things look like good, but no block production.

```
 Resolving parachain id...
2022-05-11 16:10:11 Building chain spec    
  ✓ Read parachain id for ../../../cumulus/target/release/polkadot-collator: 1000
2022-05-11 16:10:11 Building chain spec    

 Starting with a fresh authority set...
   Added Genesis Authority alice
   Added Genesis Authority bob
   Added Genesis Authority charlie
   Added Genesis Authority dave
   Added Genesis Authority eve
   Added Genesis Authority ferdie

⚙ Updating Relay Chain Genesis Configuration
  ⚠ Bad Genesis Configuration [ runtime_genesis_config: [object Object] ]

⛓ Adding Genesis Parachains
  ✓ Added Genesis Parachain 1000
Added Boot Nodes: /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30444/p2p/12D3KooWBpXHFGqv6Cn4fecVkoZog5AwKpo4srLCh82hRLCREyqQ,/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30555/p2p/12D3KooWL2Trz3SHdj69KE4u1rs8L4dNiiSVWHvPgghH5cruHpdi,/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30666/p2p/12D3KooWSRubBEXi2mepS977hbAtwcqajiuiBc4DsY12aAGBiQGt,/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30777/p2p/12D3KooWCmF9w2hKHwyjYmfBHGE4PT4yDoiv8zMtTHFXdiXQQ9GU,/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30778/p2p/12D3KooWNYx15tFrmeVk9Q768bZTby1eAo7vYJMg7W6hG7bzFQ9F,/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30779/p2p/12D3KooWAzjYTQC2rhrfq1vUgcQ9u4EtLtc2qVckArSdg5BVn9i4

2022-05-11 16:10:12 Building chain spec    
2022-05-11 16:10:13 [0]  generated 2 npos voters, 2 from validators and 0 nominators    
2022-05-11 16:10:13 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
2022-05-11 16:10:13 Took active validators from set with wrong size.    
2022-05-11 16:10:13 Took active validators from set with wrong size    
Starting Relaychain Node alice... wsPort: 9944 rpcPort: undefined port: 30444 nodeKey: c2932f775f2342b04e99242358542a4184b67fe83a7f084afc69dba8bbafd50b
Added --rpc-cors=all,--beefy,--enable-offchain-indexing=true
Starting Relaychain Node bob... wsPort: 9955 rpcPort: undefined port: 30555 nodeKey: 47913ebe0a697d07aeecbae0c0c440cbb3d3ad04947707be5853115d504d160a
Added --beefy
Starting Relaychain Node charlie... wsPort: 9966 rpcPort: undefined port: 30666 nodeKey: 1393cc7ad66e836d152b2385793243c19f9f86a6bda209ca0fd3b7c473a04977
Added --beefy
Starting Relaychain Node dave... wsPort: 9977 rpcPort: undefined port: 30777 nodeKey: f39b4dba76fc9262b239b49eb0327496faea6cdbef865227d9b10c63107ce04a
Added --beefy
Starting Relaychain Node eve... wsPort: 9978 rpcPort: undefined port: 30778 nodeKey: 83ad2741d3f342da242adfddb5f4a12c0b76c8e0944ea7532cc26fb327f2a684
Added --beefy
Starting Relaychain Node ferdie... wsPort: 9979 rpcPort: undefined port: 30779 nodeKey: 5cebfc00fb88231f57264c4925ad09fcb30a398f9b4b086a396e275841e84751
Added --beefy
2022-05-11 16:10:13          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-05-11 16:10:15          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-05-11 16:10:18          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-05-11 16:10:20          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-05-11 16:10:23          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-05-11 16:10:25          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-05-11 16:10:28          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-05-11 16:10:30          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-05-11 16:10:33          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-05-11 16:10:35          API-WS: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:9944: 1006:: connection failed
2022-05-11 16:10:38        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: beefy_getFinalizedHead
Starting a Collator for parachain 1000: 5Ec4AhPZk8STuex8Wsi9TwDtJQxKqzPJRCH7348Xtcs9vZLJ, Collator port : 31100 wsPort : 9988 rpcPort : undefined
Added --alice
Added --force-authoring
Added --chain=statemine-local
Added  to parachain
Added --execution=wasm to collator
Starting a Collator for parachain 1000: 5Ec4AhPZk8STuex8Wsi9TwDtJQxKqzPJRCH7348Xtcs9vZLJ, Collator port : 31200 wsPort : 9997 rpcPort : undefined
Added --bob
Added --force-authoring
Added --chain=statemine-local
Added  to parachain
Added --execution=wasm to collator
 POLKADOT LAUNCH COMPLETE
```

versions used are 0.9.18 tags:

```
polkadot-collator 5.3.0-b1e91afb7-x86_64-linux-gnu
polkadot 0.9.18-99cd17ddb2-x86_64-linux-gnu
```

UPDATE2:

Tried to run `statemine` out of console, failed with

```
../../../cumulus/target/release/polkadot-collator --chain "statemine-local" --port 30888 --ws-port 9988 --tmp
Error: Input("Relay chain argument error: Invalid input: `kusama-local` only supported with `kusama-native` feature enabled.")
2022-05-12 17:38:19 Polkadot collator    
2022-05-12 17:38:19 ✌️  version 5.3.0-b1e91afb7-x86_64-linux-gnu    
2022-05-12 17:38:19 ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2022    
2022-05-12 17:38:19  Chain specification: Statemine Local    
2022-05-12 17:38:19   Node name: enormous-manager-8101    
2022-05-12 17:38:19  Role: FULL    
2022-05-12 17:38:19  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/substratebAUh6O/chains/statemine_local/db/full    
2022-05-12 17:38:19 ⛓  Native runtime: statemine-800 (statemine-0.tx5.au1)    
2022-05-12 17:38:19 assembling new collators for new session 0 at #0    
2022-05-12 17:38:19 assembling new collators for new session 1 at #0
```

Comment: If you try without all the basepaths then it will run the chains in --dev mode forcing it to start fresh each time (or you could try deleting /tmp/polkadot-launch ). It can take a while for the parachain to mount onto the relay chain. Is there anything in the 9988.log that gives any hints?

Comment: thanks for the hints. afaik we rm `/tmp/polkadot-launch`. so will  try new random paths. yeah, just found it takes up to 3 minutes get blocks produced on our parachain.  waited statemine too - not helped. will try to read log.

Comment: ok. added logs. blocks are not produced. peers are initialized so. not sure why there is no nominators. may be given small amount of nodes and local chain they are not needed. i have made all up to 5 nodes on relay. and tried 2-3 nodes of statemine.

Comment: may be it relates to special parent to child relation of relay to statemine.

Answer (score 1):

`polkadot-launch` is about to be deprecated. See
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch/issues/189

You should check one of the following alternatives:

- [zombienet](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet)
- [parachain-launch](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/parachain-launch)